# How to format data in Json file with a variable assignment

Tags: java, json, getjson, jsonserializer

I am having a converting that in to Json with following code

```
    JSONObject jsonformatted = (JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJSON(map);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("myfile.json");
```

It is working fine and out put is following

```
        [ {"date":"July 4th", "event":"Independence Day"} ]
```

But I want the following format with a variable assign get value in Json

```
           jsonstr = [ {"date":"July 4th", "event":"Independence Day"} ];
```

How can i add a variable  to that

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new data using [put method in JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
JSONObject jsonformatted = (JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJSON(map);

jsonformatted .put("assign ", "some value")
```

### **Edit**

OP wants to replace ':' with '='
Well you should not do it , because its the JSON standard.
Attributes and values are assigned using : and not by =
Check this link for more info
[JSON wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)

Comment: it is giving as 

 "assign" : [ {"date":"July 4th", "event":"Independence Day"} ];

but i want = sign place of : sign